# Reporting issue: Marketing Cloud Reply Mail Management

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, email

Is there any option to create a report on all emails which go through RMM (Reply Mail Management)?

We have set up dynamic sender Profile with 5000 From Addresses and From Names.
The reply email adress is always the agent's personal email address.

We have following question:

- If a subscriber answers to an email (e.g. Agent_David@mailbox.com or
  Agent_Kyle@mailbox.com) is there any option within Marketing Cloud to see how many email answers an agent received recently / from the last emails?

Hope its understandable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with [Dynamic Reply Mail Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_dynamic_rmm_configuration.htm&type=5).

You will need to contact your Account Executive to have this feature enabled on your Marketing Cloud account though.

It will work the same way as Dynamic Sender for the most part, yet with DRMM you will need to keep the information about the agents/emails in Marketing Cloud data extensions.